# How to create HD Wallet using bitcoinj

Tags: bitcoinj

Married/multi-signature wallets and pluggable signers
How to create Hd Wallet using bitcoinj
I have tried but not understand i got the error in this
wallet.addFollowingAccountKeys(Lists.newArrayList(spouseKey), 2);